# redirecting output of ant executed in java to custom Swing element

Tags: java, swing, ant, installation, concurrency

I am creating an Ant project in java using org.apache.tools.ant.Project and executing targets of my choice.

We have a Swing UI that controls the flow of these executions ( created through ant installer project). Now the question is how to display the output of the ant build in the swing application.

I created a panel and set it as System Out and i overrode the default logger's message logged method and print any message to this System out.
But the output is not captured. Any pointers on how to accomplish this?

Thx

Comment: for better help sooner please edit you post with http://sscce.org/ demostrating your issue

Comment: You've got to find the bug first by testing each individual component in isolation to see which one isn't working.